# Extension method naming convention

Tags: c#, design-patterns, .net, naming, conventions

We are using some utility methods in our company to simplify programming.

So we have following string extension:

```
public static bool IsNoE(this string s)
{
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(s);
}
```

This is just for convenience and the intention of this question is not to discuss the sense or senseless of such methods (maintaining, ...)

The question is about the naming.

Some people think the method should be named in this way:

```
public static bool IsNullOrEmpty(this string s)
{
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(s);
}
```

The argument for the first naming is:

- It would not make sense to make extensions if they are not shorter to write.

The argument for the second naming is:

- The only reason to add such extensions is just to support programming flow. (Writing a variable and then set the cursor back to the start to surround the variable with `string.IsNull`)

So why should I prefer one version over the other? Are there any naming conventions we can refer to?

Comment: I don't think this kind of null check is common enough to warrant a helper method beyond the existing `string.IsNullOrEmpty`. In my experience most null checks take the form `if(x==null)throw new ArgumentNullException("x")`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The first naming is just plainly wrong. Want a proof? What does the next piece of code do?

```
if (this.ah == PcX.Def)
{
    this.Z.SecN.Coll();
}
```

The second naming is ok. It's explicit enough, but not too long. It's the one which is used by .NET Framework, so other developers won't be lost.

This being said, don't create aliases: you create additional code which has to be tested and maintained, while it doesn't bring anything useful to the project.

Comment: Not all aliases are created for the sake of having aliases. Eg. `String.Format` will throw an exception if the string can't be formatted (the number of `"{x}"` tokens is not right). Strings in the app I maintain are loaded in runtime because of localization. Somebody made a typo and translated a message as "sth sth {0)", the other bracket wasn't a curly one. It crashed the app. I replaced `String.Format` calls with an extension method that would recover from exception. Testing it didn't consume an awful lot of my time : )

Comment: @KonradMorawski You method is not an alias since it provides different functionality than `string.Format`.

Comment: @Konrad - but how long will finding the next localization bug take? IMO it's better not to catch those exceptions, so that you can find the bugs earlier in the development/test cycle.

Answer (score 5):

I actually use `NullOrEmpty` (on strings) as well as eg. `JoinWith` (an alias for `String.Join`).

> The argument for the first naming is:
>
> - It would not make sense to make extensions if they are not shorter to write

Extension methods **are** shorter to write even if you do keep the original name, because you don't need to refer to the `String` class explicitly.

```
String.IsNullOrEmpty(foo)
foo.IsNullOrEmpty()
```

Isn't it shorter?

Or in my case:

```
foo.NullOrEmpty()
```

I find the extension method syntax even more handy for testing whether a string is **not** null nor empty.

Compare:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(foo)) // double negation and not very readable, it's easy to miss the "!"
```

Versus:

```
if (foo.NotEmpty())
```

Having said that, I am 100% against cryptic naming such as `IsNoE`.

Comment: Try reading that without foreknowledge of what the method really does.  When I see `if (foo.NotEmpty()) ...`, I think "Hmm, that's gonna crash if `foo` is null.".  NRE-protection should be obvious.  And static methods shouldn't be made to appear instance-specific.

Comment: I feel like this is a misrepresentation of what people mean by "less code is better code". you can't really drag it down to statement-level and say "9 chars is better than 12 chars!", it's about more subtle things than that. amount of symbols in scope, types used, statements used and so on. also, as a new developer, when you see something like `str.NotEmpty()` you have NO idea what it does. does it check for null? and if it does, does it throw an argument exception? or does it return false? is whitespace empty? `string.IsNullOrEmpty(string)` is well documented and understood by all .NET devs.

Answer (score 4):

Seriously? Typing out method names is obsolete - if everyone had to type out `System.Windows.Media.TextFormatting.TextSource.GetTextEffectCharacterIndexFromTextSourceCharacterIndex` every time they used it, C# would be a dead language.

Fortunately the IDE does most of this for you, so length doesn't matter - clarity does however, so keep with the long version.

Any extension methods I create always go in their own namespace and are usually 'hungarianed' with 'Ext' at the end so I can clearly see its an extension (never want to spend time trying to figure out which class a method belongs to only to find it doesn't belong to any class! I figure it works well for interfaces (with an I prefix) and exceptions (with Exception suffix) to use this form for extensions.

Comment: I don't understand the point you make in your last paragraph. The point of extension methods is to specify the behavior of classes (or usually interfaces) that you can't specify otherwise, either because (usually bad idea) the class is not yours and you can't modify or inherit it, or because it's an interface (usually good idea; classical example: LINQ). So conceptually, they belong to a class/interface like any non-static method, just that they are written somewhere outside (which shouldn't matter when you are using them).

Comment: My point is that I go to the class and look at the methods and.. can;t find the one I wanted. So its just a hint to me that its an extension one. Conceptually they belong to the class like any other... Realistically they do not. They are a bit of an useful-but-dirty anti-pattern.

Comment: It it works for 'Exception' suffix, why not use the full 'Extensions' suffix instead of 'Ext'? Clarity matters, as you say.

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer Because I'm too lazy when writing the original method out :-)

Comment: +1 for everything except the last paragraph.  Hungarian Notation is just as obsolete as typing long method names by hand, for the same reason - Visual Studio.

Comment: @RossPatterson - a shorthand notation is useful - as you see with things like I for interfaces and similar. Just as long as it doesn't get taken to extremes.

Comment: A shorthand notation is *not* useful, even in cases like interfaces and type parameters if you have distinct syntax highlighting for them. Same with underscores on fields. *If* you aren't using IDE features, prefixes and suffixes are useful. Resharper can color just about anything differently. Don't misuse the tools provided to you.

Comment: @Magnus Tell Microsoft that! I find they help when used properly, hence *everyone* naming exceptions as they do.

Comment: They do have one advantage: Interfaces starting with an `I` and type parameters starting with a `T` avoids collisions with any concrete types. It isn't about recognition, however. The same is true of exceptions.